# Highcharts: Error bars in drill-down charts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, drilldown

I have a Highcharts chart where I used error bars to represent uncertainty in a reported measurement.

This chart also has a drill-down for every series. When we drill down, the data should also show the Error bars for the new columns that are displayed.

This is not working right now. The Error bar series shows up for the main series, but not for drill-down ones.

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmunger/KFpJC/5/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'

        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            id: 'TokyoID',
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [{
                name: 'namey',
                y: 49.9,
                drilldown: 'tokyo 1'
            }, {
                y: 71.5,
                name: 'namex',
                drilldown: 'tokyo 2'
            }]

        }, {
            name: 'errTest',
            type: 'errorbar',
            linkedTo: 'TokyoID',
            data: [{
                high: 53,
                low: 46.9
            }, {
                high: 73,
                low: 69.9
            }]

        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                id: 'tokyo 1',
                data: [{
                    y: 39.9,
                    name: 'name1'
                }, {
                    y: 31.5,
                    name: 'name2'
                }]

            }, {
            name: 'drillDownErrTest',
           linkedTo: 'tokyo 1',
            type: 'errorbar',
            data: [{
                high: 53,
                low: 46.9
            }, {
                high: 73,
                low: 69.9
            }]

        }]
        }
    });
});
```

How can I display error bars in drill-down series? Is it supported at this time?

EDIT: There also seems to be a bug when we have more than 1 parent series: on drill-up, the second Error Bar series is not positioned correctly. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmunger/3U4uA/ ... Drill down, then drill up: The 2nd error bar doesn't seem to be linked to the second series anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you click on a specific point, you will drilldown to the specific series linked by `drilldown:ID`. `linkedTo` option is to connect series legends, not drilldowns ([docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.linkedTo)).

However, when you set drilldown for both series points for a category, then you can click on a category name to drilldown to both of them, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/KFpJC/7/

About second issue, indeed looks like a bug, I have reported that: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2918

Thanks!

Comment: In your example, I see how I can display error bars in drilldowns when clicking on a category, but is it possible to display them when I click on a specific column (point)?

Comment: The only thing that cross my mind is to add them manually in [drilldown event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown) and remove on [drillup event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drillup).

Comment: I think it would be simpler if I could just disable drilldowns on specific points and just leave drilldowns per category... any simple way to do that?

Comment: I don't think so. You have drilldown event in chart, but it's called on drilldown, not on a click.

Comment: Regarding your first comment abrout drilldown and drillup events: I am trying to make it work but am having a hard time understanding how it works. In this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KFpJC/9/ , I can add the errorbar series to the drilldown, but then there's a problem when adding the drilldown series... do you know how I can make this work?

Comment: I was thinking about adding second series as standard series, not drilldown. One point = one drilldown, you can't use the same point and add two drilldowns. See: http://jsfiddle.net/KFpJC/10/

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out, looks like it's working in your example, I'll just have to add a drillup event to get rid of the drilldown errorbar series on drillup.

Comment: Still trying to get this done. The problem is that my data is retrieved from an XML file, so I create all my series and data before a drilldown or drillup happens. Si I have my drilldown errorbars set as a parent series, but when I try to show them on drilldown nothing happens... see this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmunger/KFpJC/13/

Comment: Looks like when you are on drilldown you can't show one of main series

Comment: But isn't it a main series (tokyo drilldown errorbar) in your example here http://jsfiddle.net/KFpJC/10/ ?

Comment: I'm a bit lost. What is wrong with my example? I guess initialized series couldn't be displayed (are indexed to specific level or something like that).

Comment: No, your example works, but I guess what you are trying to say is that the errorbar series must be added with chart.addSeries on the drilldown event, or else it won't work, right?

Comment: Additionally, it seems the drilldown series must also be added (with AddSeriesAsDrilldown) on the drilldown event.

Comment: Yes, I think that's required. I have used that example as base: [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown) - 'Acync drilldown'.

Comment: I think I got it to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmunger/KFpJC/17/ ... Do you see a better way or simpler way to do it?

Comment: I think it's a nice solution, but error-bar drilldown doesn't work?

Comment: You mean when clicking on an error bar series? If so, no, it doesn't work on the example but I don't allow drilldown or tooltips with error bars in my real charts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51749/discussion-between-the-jakester-and-pawel-fus)